# Need help parsing the meaning of "i.~"

Tags: j

I'm trying to understand the solution for day 1 part 2:  https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Advent_Of_Code#Part_2

```
PART2=: >: _1 i.~ +/\ 1 _1 mp '()'=/read'input'
```

I feel like I understand most of what's going on here but I'm not sure how to interpret the

```
i.~
```

part.  I know what "i." generally does but I'm confused by the "~" here.  My understanding is that "~" duplicates the right args to also be on the left.  But here we already have a "_1" so I'm not sure how to interpret the semantics of this.

Also any tips on how to track this down myself are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The adverb *commute* `~` simply flips the arguments to the dyadic verb it’s attached to. So `3 % 5` is three-fifths but `3 %~ 5` is five-thirds (aka `5 % 3`). So, in your verb, the dyad `i.` is the one you’re familiar with (index of), but the `~` makes the constant `_1` its *right* argument, even though, textually, it appears to its left. Thus, the `i.` is looking for the first `_1` in the result of `1 _1 mp …`.

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for.  i was looking around in the vocab guide but somehow didn't see it .  thanks!

Comment: You can find it spelled out in the [NuVoc here](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/tilde#dyadic) or in the [original J Vocabulary here](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d220v.htm).  The NuVoc is designed to be more accessible, the Vocabulary canonical. In the NuVoc, it's expressed as "Thus, x u~ y is the same as y u x".  The Vocabulary states it more mathematically, with the equivalence assertion `x u~ y ↔ y u x` (on the right half of the page, since we're talking about dyad `i.` here, instead of the monad).

Comment: interesting.  even with you pointing it out i would have had trouble finding this on the page.  still lots to learn.  :)

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>It seems like my comments discouraged others from providing the typical official answers in answer format. So I’m reproducing them as an answer proper.</sub>

The adverb *commute* `~` simply flips the arguments to the dyadic verb it’s attached to. So `3 % 5` is three-fifths but `3 %~ 5` is five-thirds (aka `5 % 3`).

So, in your verb, the dyad `i.` is the one you’re familiar with (*index of*), but the `~` makes the constant `_1` its *right* argument, even though, textually, it appears to its left. Thus, the `i.` is looking for the first `_1` in the result of `+/\ 1 _1 mp …`.

You can find it spelled out in the [NuVoc here](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/tilde#dyadic) or in the [original J Vocabulary here](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d220v.htm). The NuVoc is designed to be more accessible, the Vocabulary canonical.

In the NuVoc, it's expressed as *Thus, `x u~ y` is the same as `y u x`*. The Vocabulary states it more mathematically, with the equivalence assertion `x u~ y ↔ y u x` (on the right half of the page, since we're talking about dyad `i.` here, instead of the monad).

Comment: thanks.  just need more practice deciphering the NuVoc but i'm getting there